# Removing columns from an index request in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Hi I currently have the code:

```
matrixed.data <- data.matrix(df[1:row.dim,7:col.dim])
```

Where the row.dim and col.dim are variables for the size of the whole frame. I would like to remove the column "df$WEATHER" that is included in the col.dim selection but don't know how to word it. I have tried adding - df$WEATHER and !df$WEATHER inside the bracket but fear I'm misinterpreting the scope of these commands.

Is it possible to do this without creating a new col.dim variable; I'm trying to keep the code as limitless as possible as the data frame may increase in size in the future.

Comment: `df[1:row.dim, setdiff(7:col.dim,which(names(df) == 'Wheather')) ]` ?

Comment: Can you provide an example?
For instance, let us see `df` head and `row.dim` and `col.dim`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you digEmAll! I thought it would be reasonably simple I'm just a bit too green at R to think of something like that. For others what worked for me was:

```
(df[1:row.dim, setdiff(7:col.dim,which(names(df) == "WEATHER"))])
```